# Path helper doesn't automatically get object's id anymore?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

for some reason this one doesn't work anymore

```
admin_club_path(club)
```

but following does work

```
admin_club_path(club.id)
```

Anyone know what the reason could be?

This is the error message:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/clubs", :id=>#<Club id: 98, name: "1. FSV Mainz 05 II", image: "mainz05.gif", photo_id: 3, league_id: 5, approved: false, permalink: "1-fsv-mainz-05-ii", created_at: "2011-11-22 16:43:13", updated_at: "2011-11-22 16:43:13">}
```

Apparently it takes the whoe object as id but why?

The routes seem to be alright:

```
           admin_clubs GET        /admin/clubs(.:format) {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/clubs"}
                       POST       /admin/clubs(.:format) {:action=>"create", :controller=>"admin/clubs"}
        new_admin_club GET        /admin/clubs/new(.:format) {:action=>"new", :controller=>"admin/clubs"}
       edit_admin_club GET        /admin/clubs/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"admin/clubs"}
            admin_club GET        /admin/clubs/:id(.:format) {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/clubs"}
                       PUT        /admin/clubs/:id(.:format) {:action=>"update", :controller=>"admin/clubs"}
                       DELETE     /admin/clubs/:id(.:format) {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"admin/clubs"}
                  club GET        /clubs/:id(.:format) {:action=>"show", :controller=>"clubs"}
```

Comment: It seems all OK to me. Please post your model... maybe there is something wrong with it. It could be something related to the to_param method...

Comment: Probably some routes are in conflict, please check your routes file for similar routes, maybe change some of the orders. Try to put the admin_club route to the very top.

Comment: I have the same issue, but I do not use the permalink gem. I do not mess up with to_param and it worked in rails 3.1, however after having upgraded to 3.2 it broke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucapette gave me the right hint. I'm using permalink gem which had following in the model:

```
permalink :name, :unique => true, :to_param => %w(id name)
```

after I removed the :to_param parameter it all works fine. I will report it to the developer of them gem!

Thanks lucapette and dombesz!

Comment: I think you would have said the right hint ;) Anyway, mark your own answer as accepted. It will help future readers.